# Get Google Datastore entity using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying with no success to retrieve my Api key for a service stored as Entity in the Google Cloud Datastore from my NodeJs server running on GAE.
I can't find any useful documentation, could someone help me to find out how to retrieve the Entity?
Thank you in advance

[image: My Entity on Datastore]

My not working code:

```
const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const projectId = 'abcdefghi';
const ds = new Datastore({
  projectId: projectId,
});
const keyName = 'UNSPLASH_KEY';
const kind = 'Strings';
const stringKey = ds.key([kind, keyName]);

var appkey = 'not set';

var entity  = {
key: stringKey,
value: appkey,
};

entity = ds.get(stringKey);
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @DanCornilescu i don't understand which type of structure should i receive from ds.get(), i can't find any useful example, at the moment if i console.log the result of the get() i see 'Promise { <pending> }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object you get indicates that the `.get()` function is an async one and represents the **eventual completion (or failure)** of that function execution, not its result.

To see the actual result of the function execution (if, of course, it succeeds) you need to use the [`await` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) with it:

```
entity = await ds.get(stringKey);
```

This is shown in the [Retrieving an entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity) example:

> ```
> const [entity] = await datastore.get(taskKey);
> ```

As for the structure - the result is a dictionary with an entry for each of the entity's property. You can manually add a property to the entity in the console and you'll see it in the result next time you'll get the entity. From [Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) (emphasis mine):

> Data objects in Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode are known as
>   *entities*. An entity has one or more named *properties*, each of which can have one or more values. **Entities of the same kind do not
>   need to have the same properties, and an entity's values for a given
>   property do not all need to be of the same data type**. (If necessary,
>   an application can establish and enforce such restrictions in its own
>   data model.)

Comment: Okay thank you, but how should i structure the entity object returned?  that's still not clear to me
Thank you for your help

Comment: Okey perfect i was able to make it working now, thank you much!