# NodeJS: How to include environment variable from CircleCI into the application

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, environment-variables, circleci-2.0

In my front end application, I'm storing sensitive information in the environment and using them as following:

```
const client_secret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
```

On local development, I use [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to pass in the values in `.env` file

```
CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXX
```

The `.env` file is not committed.

I use CircleCI for my deployment process, and saved the `CLIENT_SECRET` value in CircleCI environment variables, but how can I pass into the application?

This is my CircleCI `config.yml`:

```
      - deploy:
          name: Deploy
          command: |
            ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT:=test}
            VERSION=`date "+%Y-%m-%dt%H%M"`
            if [ "${ENVIRONMENT}" = "production" ]; then
                APP_FILE=app-prod.yaml
            else
                APP_FILE=app.yaml
            fi
            gcloud app deploy ${APP_FILE} --quiet --version ${VERSION}
```

I can do this in `app.yaml`:

```
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
  CLIENT_SECRET: XXXXX
```

But I don't want to include the sensitive information into the `.yaml` file and commit them. Does anyone know any way I can pass environment values into the application?

> I'm using Google Cloud Platform, and `gcloud app deploy` [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) doesn't seem to have a flag to include the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Using bash script to create a `.env` file with environment variables manually**

`app.yaml.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo """
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
resources:
  memory_gb: 4.0
  disk_size_gb: 10
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'test'
  CLIENT_SECRET: \"$CLIENT_SECRET\"
"""
```

`config.yml`

```yaml
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: chmod permissions
          command: chmod -R 755 ./
      - run:
          name: Copy across app.yaml config
          command: ./app.yaml.sh > ./app.yaml
      - deploy:
          name: Deploy
          command: |
            VERSION=`date "+%Y-%m-%dt%H%M"`
            gcloud app deploy app.yaml --quiet --version ${VERSION}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading about it, it's indeed, as you mentioned, that the only "official" way to set environment variables, it's by setting them in the `app.yaml`  - [this article](https://dev.to/mungell/google-cloud-app-engine-environment-variables-5990) provides more information on it. Considering that, I went to search further and I have found this good question from the Community - accessible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669528/securely-storing-environment-variables-in-gae-with-app-yaml) - where some workarounds are provided.

For example, the one that you mentioned, about creating a second file with the values and call it in the `app.yaml` is a good one. You can them use the `.gitignore` for the file not exist in the repository - in case you are using one. Another option would be to use Cloud Datastore to store the information and use it in your application. This way, Datastore would keep this information secured and accessible for your application, without becoming public within your App Engine configuration.

I just thought a good idea of adding this information here, with the article and question included, in case you want more information! :)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for the research! Datastore seems like a proper/correct way to do this kind of job, and this seems like the way for NodeJS to retrieve entity from the datastore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197844/get-google-datastore-entity-using-nodejs

Comment: That's great! Thanks for confirming and appreciate you providing this other link from the Community!