# Receiving unhandled promise rejection warning; async/await not resolving promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-applications, google-cloud-datastore

I've been researching this for a few days now, but I can't seem to find the problem.

I have a GCloud web app running Express, using bcrypt for password encryption and Google Firestore in Datastore mode for db.

Here is my route code, this contains all the code that is potentially problematic.

**EDIT**
after some more research, and after providing comments on the two posters who have offered help/answers, the following is my code after a few refactors, still receiving the same error/s.
**EDIT**
more research, and another refactor:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = new Datastore();

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

function getUser(username){
  return datastore.get(datastore.key(['user', username]))
    .then((user) => user)
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}

function authUser(username, password){
  return comparePass(password, getUser(username).hash);
}

function comparePass(password, hash){
  return bcrypt.compare(password, hash)
    .then(result => result)
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}

function hashPass(password){
  return bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
    .then((result) => result)
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  const auth = authUser(req.body.username, req.body.password);
  if (auth === false) {res.redirect('/login');} else {
    req.session.loggedIn = true;
    req.session.username = req.body.username;
    req.session.save(function(err) {
      if(err){console.error(err);}
      res.redirect('/users/show/'+req.body.username);
    });
  }
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.destroy(function(err){
    if(err){console.error(err);}
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('/users/new');
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.body.notarobot !== "true"){res.redirect('/');}
  if(req.body.password == req.body.confirm){
    const userHash = hashPass(req.body.password);
    datastore.insert({
      key: datastore.key(['user', req.body.username]),
      data: {
        username: req.body.username,
        hash: userHash
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("successful entry")
      req.session.loggedIn = true;
      req.session.username = req.body.username;
      req.session.save(function(err) {
        if(err){console.error(err);}
        res.redirect('/users/show/'+req.body.username);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      req.session.error = "User already exists, choose a new username";
      res.redirect('/signup');
    });
  } else {
    req.session.error = "Passwords don't match";
console.error("Passwords don't match");
    res.redirect('/signup');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**EDIT**
I've edited the above code to match my current server code:
after refactoring from async/await to resolving with .then().catch(), login is working, but now when the post route to signup is called, the hashPass function is returning an unresolved promise, causing the datastore.insert call to error. Still not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197844/get-google-datastore-entity-using-nodejs .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Google Datastore entity using NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197844/get-google-datastore-entity-using-nodejs)

Comment: The issue seems to be the promise not resolving from the datastore.get call. Refactored, same issue:
async function getUser(username){
try{
    var user = await datastore.get(datastore.key(['user', username]));
    return await Promise.resolve(user);
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    return false;
  }
}

async function authUser(username, password){
  try{
    var data = await Promise.resolve(getUser(username));
    return await comparePass(password, data.hash);
  }catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    return false
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on Promises but I think you should use `return await <your promise>` rather than just `return promise` (see this [article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/return-await-promise-javascript/) for an explanation)

i.e. try the code below for authUser and follow the same principle for the others

```
async function authUser(username, password){
  try{
    const data = await datastore.get(datastore.key(['user', username]));
    const auth = await comparePass(password, data.hash);
    
    // Use a return await Promise so that your catch block actually
    // catches the exception if there's one. 

    return await auth

    // You can also try this variation
    // return await Promise.resolve(auth)

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    return false
  }

}
```

Comment: I have deduced the unresolved promise is coming from the datastore.get call. I even separated the datastore get query into its own function:

async function getUser(username){
try{
    var user = await datastore.get(datastore.key(['user', username]));
    return await Promise.resolve(user);
  }catch(e){
    console.error(e);
    return false;
  }
}

async function authUser(username, password){
  try{
    var data = await Promise.resolve(getUser(username));
    return await comparePass(password, data.hash);
  }catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    return false
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

After more research and refactoring, I have gotten the code to work as expected, here is the code I used:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = new Datastore();

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

function getUser(username){
  return datastore.get(datastore.key(['user', username]))
    .then((user) => user)
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}

function authUser(username, password){
  return comparePass(password, getUser(username).hash);
}

function comparePass(password, hash){
  return bcrypt.compare(password, hash)
    .then(result => result)
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}

function hashPass(username, password){
  const userHash = bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
    .then((result) => result)
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  return createUser(username, userHash);
}

function createUser(username, passHash){
  return datastore.insert({
    key: datastore.key(['user', username]),
    data: {
      username: username,
      hash: passHash
    }
  })
  .then(() => true)
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return false
  });
}

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  const auth = authUser(req.body.username, req.body.password);
  if (auth === false) {res.redirect('/login');} else {
    req.session.loggedIn = true;
    req.session.username = req.body.username;
    req.session.save(function(err) {
      if(err){console.error(err);}
      res.redirect('/users/show/'+req.body.username);
    });
  }
});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.destroy(function(err){
    if(err){console.error(err);}
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next){
  res.redirect('/users/new');
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.body.notarobot !== "true"){res.redirect('/');}
  if(req.body.password == req.body.confirm){
    req.session.loggedIn = hashPass(req.body.username, req.body.password);
    if(req.session.loggedIn){
      req.session.username = req.body.username;
      req.session.save((err) => {
        if(err){console.error(err);}
        res.redirect('/users/show/'+req.body.username);
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect('/users/new');
    }
  } else {
    req.session.error = "Passwords don't match";
    console.error("Passwords don't match");
    res.redirect('/users/new');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I moved away from async/await and decided to resolve promises using .then().catch(), and that seemed to be the catalyst for everything else. Still not entirely sure why it's working this way (I have some ideas, I'll learn more as I go)

Thanks to those who suggested things, the prods in the right direction helped!